# Adaptive thresholding for scanned images

Tags: vb.net, image, threshold

I would like to improve a number of images accquired with document scanning, does anybody have any VB sample code for dynamic thresholding to achieve a result something similar to the images shown at the bottom of the page;

http://www.datastor-ltd.co.uk/component/content/article/39-microfilm-scanning/104-the-benefits-of-scanning-in-greyscale

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Otsu's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsus_method).  It's quite simple an easy to implement -- you should be able to transform Wikipedia's pseudo-code into VB in no time.

Otsu's method will give you a threshold (single value) -- you can then use that threshold to binarize the image.  The thresholding code is also trivial.

Comment: Otsu thresholding is not dynamic (or adaptive as in the question's title) in any way, it is a global threshold.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  Looking at the question after all this time, I realized I haven't quite answered it here.